# Postgres - pg_statistic vacuum timeout

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, vacuum

In my Aurora Postgres server I continuously see a vacuum timeout every minute for the following:

```
autovacuum: VACUUM pg_catalog.pg_statistic
```

I tried doing it manually and got following output:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_catalog.pg_statistic"
INFO:  "pg_statistic": found 0 removable, 409109 nonremovable row versions in 19981 out of 19990 pages
DETAIL:  408390 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 4230263474
There were 0 unused item identifiers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 9 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.06 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.07 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_2619"
INFO:  "pg_toast_2619": found 0 removable, 272673 nonremovable row versions in 61558 out of 61558 pages
DETAIL:  219 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 4230263474
There were 0 unused item identifiers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.14 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.14 s.
VACUUM

Query returned successfully in 5 secs 55 msec.
```

Anyone can point to the reason why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Is there any timeout log from your AWS Aurora?

Comment: @D-Shih I have attached the image

Comment: Must be one of [these reasons](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/). Fix the problem and try again.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It was none of the three. The long-running process is pgadmin, no orphaned prepared transactions and no abandoned replication slots

Comment: Then it was the first reason, a long running transaction. Make sure *not* do disable autocommit in pgAdmin!

Comment: Calling this a "timeout" is an Aurora-invented weirdness.  This is just the vacuum throttling itself to avoid competing too much with your "foreground" processes.  It does not indicate a problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe We don't run pgadmin all the time, but the vacuum timeout is continuous. I also tried running VACUUM FULL, that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: @jjanes I am not concerned with continuous timeout. The concern is vacuum is unable to delete 408390 dead tuples even on VACUUM FULL.

Comment: Neither `VACUUM` nor `VACUUM (FULL)` can solve the problem as long as you are holding the transaction open.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I killed the pgadmin process, but still I am seeing the timeouts in AWS.

Comment: That would be cool, according to what jjanes said above (I know nothing about Aurora). The important point is that `VACUUM (VERBOSE)` shows that dead tuples get cleaned up.

Comment: You say you aren't concerned with the timeouts, but with the dead but nonremovable tuples.  But then you keep reporting the timeouts are still here.  But are the dead but nonremovable tuples still there?  You killed one process with a long-open transaction, but there might be more, so go back the re-assess that.

Answer (score 3):

I think your autovacuum might work as well, [Timeout:VacuumDelay](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Reference.Waitevents.html) might only be a metric From AWS

> A process is waiting in a cost-based vacuum delay point.

The most similar setting is [`autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-VACUUM-COST-DELAY) which exists in PostgreSQL.

That want to slow down autovacuum. autovacuum will sleep for these many milliseconds when a cleanup reaching `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` cost is done.

We can try to use `pg_stat_user_tables` to verify the latest time of autovacuum.

```
SELECT
  schemaname, relname,
  last_autovacuum,
  last_autoanalyze
FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```